# Associative property proof for conjunction and disjunction in natural deduction

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, natural-deduction

I am fairly new to natural deduction, and I don't seem to get it. I was given a task of proving through natural deduction associative property of logical conjunction and disjunction. So, I should prove this:

(A ∧ B) ∧ C ⇒ A ∧ (B ∧ C)

A ∧ (B ∧ C) ⇒ (A ∧ B) ∧ C

and

(A ∨ B) ∨ C ⇒ A ∨ (B ∨ C)

A ∨ (B ∨ C) ⇒ (A ∨ B) ∨ C

I would be really grateful if someone could explain to me what steps I should take in order to prove it, as I am new to logic and, unlike Hilbert-systems, don't really get natural deduction...

Comment: Hint. To prove the distributivity for conjunction, decompose a premise by applying $\land$-elimination and apply $\land$-introduction to decomposed one.

Comment: Quite simple... Consider the first one: assume as premise $(A \land B) \land C$ and apply $\land$-elim to get $(A \land B)$ and $C$; then $\land$-elim again to get $A$ and $B$. Now that we have unpacked them, use $\land$-intro twice in the requested order to get: $A \land (B \land C)$.

Comment: To prove the distributivity for disjunction, it is sufficient to see each propositional individual like $A$ proves $A\lor (B\lor C)$ (why?)

Comment: The same for the second one.

Comment: For the last two, use $\lor$-elim and $\lor$-intro.

Comment: What rules do you have?  There are many different systems with different rules, so it's hard to help you not knowing exactly what rules you have to work with. Are you using some specific textbook maybe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use first conjunction eliminiation to from the premise show $A$, $B$ and $C$ respectively and then conjunction introduction to show the consequence. Then you use the deduction theorem.

For example:

$$\begin{align}
(A\land B)\land C&\vdash (A\land B)\land C \\
(A\land B)\land C&\vdash (A\land B) \\
(A\land B)\land C&\vdash A \\
(A\land B)\land C&\vdash B \\
(A\land B)\land C&\vdash C \\
(A\land B)\land C&\vdash B\land C \\
(A\land B)\land C&\vdash A\land(B\land C) \\
&\vdash(A\land B)\land C \Rightarrow A\land(B\land C)
\end{align}$$

For the disjunction case you'll use case analysis. Basically the key step is that you show that both $(A\lor B)\Rightarrow A\lor (B\lor C)$ and $C\Rightarrow A\lor (B\lor C)$. Then from the assumption $(A\lor B)\lor C$ you can conclude $A\lor (B\lor C)$. The first implication follows pretty directly from disjunction elimination while the second requires an extra step (from $C$ we can first conclude $B\lor C$ and in turn from that conclude $A\lor (B\lor C)$.

Comment: So if I get it correctly, (A∧B)∧C is the only assumption I need? Are terms left of the implication those I choose as assumptions? Is there limit to how many assumptions I can make and how do I pick them? Is the process analogue for other direction and disjunction?

Sorry for bombarding you with questions like this. Textbooks in my native language are not that comprehensive and what I read online confused me a bit, but I really want to grasp the concept of this.

Thank you very much for your initial answer!

Comment: Yes, for using the deduction theorem you assume the premise and from that assumption you prove the consequence and then you discharge the assumption as you conclude that the implication holds. Here what's left of the $\vdash$ is assumption(s), and it's discharged as I conclude the implication. For the case with disjunction it's not exactly the same, then you combine disjunction introduction and case analysis (I'll update with an example of that later).

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. It helped me not only solve the task given to me, but also to better understand the concept of natural deduction. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

For the first two problems, the conjunction-elimination rule(s) allow you to start with the conjunction and then break it down into the letters.  Then you put the letters into some formulas to get to the right-hand side of the arrow.

For the second two, you can make assumptions which correspond to the proper subformulas of the disjunction.  Note you can arbitrarily make as many assumptions as you like in natural deduction, so long as you keep track of the scope of each assumption.  A proper subformula is a formula S which lies within a formula F such that the number of symbols of S is less than the number of symbols of F (every 'A' in a different position is a different formula in this definition).  Since you can make always make more assumptions in the context of natural deduction, you can make the assumptions slowly as if you were breaking the disjunctions down into it's subformulas.  Then using the disjunction-introduction rules you can reach the desired conclusion.  Then using conditonal-introduction you can show that hypotheses implied the conclusion allowing you to use disjunction-elimination to produce the right-hand side of the arrow.